# How to mass rename files in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to work out a file rename program based on ruby, as a programming exercise for myself (I am aware of rename under linux, but I want to learn Ruby, and rename is not available in Mac).

From the code below, the issue is that the `.include?` method always returns false even though I see the filename contains such search pattern. If I comment out the `include?` check, `gsub()` does not seem to generate a new file name at all (i.e. file name remains the same). So can someone please take a look at see what I did wrong? Thanks a bunch in advance!

Here is the expected behavior: 
Assuming that in current folder there are three files: a1.jpg, a2.jpg, and a3.jpg
The Ruby script should be able to rename it to b1.jpg, b2.jpg, b3.jpg

```
#!/Users/Antony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby

puts "Enter the file search query"
searchPattern = gets
puts "Enter the target to replace"
target = gets
puts "Enter the new target name"
newTarget = gets
Dir.glob("./*").sort.each do |entry|
  origin = File.basename(entry, File.extname(entry))
  if origin.include?(searchPattern)
    newEntry = origin.gsub(target, newTarget)
    File.rename( origin, newEntry )
    puts "Rename from " + origin + " to " + newEntry
  end
end
```

Comment: What input are you providing for the three `gets` prompts?

Comment: I seriously think `rename` command can do better in that...

Comment: @texasbruce, there is no rename command in mac. maybe macports have something, but only found a bunch of perl scripts. But as I suggested earlier, it is a ruby exercise for me

Comment: @Antony good for you ;) I tried before but just ended up calling rename...To go a little further, maybe you want to wrap up some file utility functions in a gem and post it. I am really upset about the File and Dir lib ruby provides.

Comment: Not in front of one right now, but `mv "old location" "new location"` doesn't work in MacOS terminal??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Slightly modified version:

```
puts "Enter the file search query"
searchPattern = gets.strip
puts "Enter the target to replace"
target = gets.strip
puts "Enter the new target name"
newTarget = gets.strip
Dir.glob(searchPattern).sort.each do |entry|
  if File.basename(entry, File.extname(entry)).include?(target)
    newEntry = entry.gsub(target, newTarget)
    File.rename( entry, newEntry )
    puts "Rename from " + entry + " to " + newEntry
  end
end
```

Key differences:

- Use `.strip` to remove the trailing newline that you get from `gets`.  Otherwise, this newline character will mess up all of your match attempts.
- Use the user-provided search pattern in the `glob` call instead of globbing for everything and then manually filtering it later.
- Use `entry` (that is, the complete filename) in the calls to `gsub` and `rename` instead of `origin`.  `origin` is really only useful for the `.include?` test.  Since it's a fragment of a filename, it can't be used with `rename`.  I removed the `origin` variable entirely to avoid the temptation to misuse it.

For your example folder structure, entering `*.jpg`, `a`, and `b` for the three input prompts (respectively) should rename the files as you are expecting.

Comment: Ahh! Thanks for the explanation. At least from the documentation (ruby-doc.org), it seems to show that strip (removes leading and trailing white spaces), and chomp (removes newlines), so I ended up with gets.chomp.strip Hopefully it is not overkill. Anyway the script works perfectly!

Comment: @Antony- Newlines are part of what Ruby considers "whitespace", so doing both `chomp` and `strip` is redundant.  `strip` does everything that `chomp` does, plus more.

Answer (score 4):

I used the accepted answer to fix a bunch of copied files' names.

```
Dir.glob('./*').sort.each do |entry|
  if File.basename(entry).include?(' copy')
    newEntry = entry.gsub(' copy', '')
    File.rename( entry, newEntry )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `gets` returns a newline at the end of the string. So, if you type "foo" then `searchPattern` becomes `"foo\n"`. The simplest fix is:

```
searchPattern = gets.chomp
```

---

I might rewrite your code slightly:

```
$stdout.sync
print "Enter the file search query: "; search  = gets.chomp
print "Enter the target to replace: "; target  = gets.chomp
print "  Enter the new target name: "; replace = gets.chomp
Dir['*'].each do |file|
  # Skip directories
  next unless File.file?(file)
  old_name = File.basename(file,'.*')
  if old_name.include?(search)
    # Are you sure you want gsub here, and not sub?
    # Don't use `old_name` here, it doesn't have the extension
    new_name = File.basename(file).gsub(target,replace)
    File.rename( file, new_path )
    puts "Renamed #{file} to #{new_name}" if $DEBUG
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out chomp. Learning something new every day.

Comment: Where is the argument "new_path" that you're sending into File.rename getting set?  Perhaps you meant  File.rename( file, new_name ) instead? Otherwise, I would give this +1

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short version I've used today (without pattern matching)

Save this as rename.rb file and run it inside the command prompt with **ruby rename.rb**

```
count = 1
newname = "car"
Dir["/path/to/folder/*"].each do |old|
  File.rename(old, newname + count.to_s)
  count += 1
end
```

I had /Copy of _MG_2435.JPG converted into car1, car2, ...

Answer (score 1):

I made a small script to rename the entire DBZ serie by seasons and implement this:

```
count = 1
new_name = "Dragon Ball Z S05E"
format_file = ".mkv"
Dir.glob("dragon ball Z*").each do |old_name|
  File.rename(old_name, new_name + count.to_s + format_file)
  count += 1
end
```

The result would be: 
    *Dragon Ball Z S05E1
    Dragon Ball Z S05E2
    Dragon Ball Z S05E3*

Answer (score 0):

In a folder, I wanted to remove the trailing underscore `_` of any audio filename while keeping everything else. Sharing my code here as it might help someone.
What the program does:

1. Prompts the user for the:

   - Directory path: `c:/your/path/here` (make sure to use slashes `/`, not backslashes, `\`, and without the final one).
   - File extension: `mp3` (without the dot `.`)
   - Trailing characters to remove: `_`
2. Looks for any file ending with `c:/your/path/here/filename_.mp3` and renames it `c:/your/path/here/filename.mp3` while keeping the file’s original extension.

```
puts 'Enter directory path'

path = gets.strip

directory_path = Dir.glob("#{path}/*")

# Get file extension

puts 'Enter file extension'

file_extension = gets.strip

# Get trailing characters to remove

puts 'Enter trailing characters to remove'

trailing_characters = gets.strip

suffix = "#{trailing_characters}.#{file_extension}"

# Rename file if condition is met

directory_path.each do |file_path|
  next unless file_path.end_with?(suffix)

  File.rename(file_path, "#{file_path.delete_suffix(suffix)}.#{file_extension}")
end
```