# Ruby: Rename all files within a user given directory from .txt to text

Tags: ruby, fileutils

some help here would be appreciated.  The goal is to rename all .txt files to .text from a user entered directory in ruby.  I have to use fileutils as a requirement.  When I run my current script I do not receive any errors.  However, nothing happens either...  I'm sure one of you could probably help me pinpoint the issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
#This program was written by me
puts “what directory would you like to change? “
require 'fileutils'
pathname = gets.chomp   
def rename(pathname)
    currentdir = Dir.new('.')
    newfile = FileTest.exists?(pathname.to_s)
    if pathname != "q"
        if newfile == "true"
            require 'fileutils'
                    newfile.each do |f|
                    FileUtils.mv "#{File.dirname(f)}/#{File.basename(f, '.*')}.txt", "#{File.dirname(f)}/#{File.basename(f,'.*')}.text"
                    end
        elsif currentdir
            require 'fileutils'
            (currentdir).each do |f|
                FileUtils.mv "#{File.dirname(f)}/#{File.basename(f, '.*')}.txt", "#{File.dirname(f)}/#{File.basename(f,'.*')}.text"
            end
        else
            puts "Invalid Path" 
        end
    end
end
```

EDIT: I think I know the problem now, but don't know where to put the code.  I need to cd to the directory that the user inputs, that should be the reason that I'm only able to change the .txt files in the home directory.

This question is different from one of the comments suggested because the requirement is to use fileutils and have the user enter the directory they would like to edit. This entry looks for a file name from ANYWHERE and does not use fileutils

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mass rename files in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758694/how-to-mass-rename-files-in-ruby)

Comment: Could that be because you never actually call the method `rename`?

Comment: It's not the same though.  The requirement is to use fileutils and have the user enter the directory they would like to edit.  This entry looks for a file name from ANYWHERE and does not use fileutils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand from Your code,

1) You were not calling `rename` function

2) Your `rename` function had unnecessary checking of `newfile`, `currentdir` - if You want execute from current dir, it will understand "." symbol and will do glob in current dir.

I've moved `pathname != "q"` to outside of `rename` because of rename must do renaming, nothing else.

So final code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
#This program was written by me

require 'fileutils'

def rename(pathname)
  if File.directory?(pathname.to_s)
    puts "renaming files in path"+pathname.to_s
    Dir.glob(File.dirname(pathname.to_s)+"/*.txt").each do |f|
      FileUtils.mv f, "#{File.dirname(f)}/#{File.basename(f,'.*')}.text"
      puts "#{File.basename} => #{File.basename(f,'.*')}.text"
    end
  else
    puts "Invalid Path" 
  end
end

puts "what directory would you like to change? "
pathname = gets.chomp

if pathname != "q"
  rename(pathname)
end
```

p.s. normal user will just call:

```
rename -S .txt .text /path/to/files/*.txt
```

or:

```
rename -S .txt .text ./*.txt
```

Comment: Running into the same problem I pretty much started out with.  I run the script and nothing happens.  No errors though.

It does however alert me if the path is not valid.  It did not do that previously.

Comment: Can You write how You call the script and what You pass as path?

Comment: Also be sure that there is a file(s) with that extension in path You define

Comment: I don't know what's going on, but when I do the home directory it works (sometimes).. When I do it on a subdirectory, it isn't working at all, but it's not giving me an error.  If I type in something that's not a directory it does call it out as not a valid path.

Comment: I've updated my answer it will output path and progress of operations (see puts). Hope it will give You info what's happening.

Comment: I think I know the problem now, but don't know where to put the code.  I need to cd to the directory that the user inputs, that should be the reason that I'm only able to change the .txt files in the home directory.

Comment: You're wrong. I think problem is with path that You type. I hope You understand what that means `FileUtils.mv f, "#{File.dirname(f)}/#{File.basename(f,'.*')}.text"`